# Traditional Practice to initialize the field members of a class

Tags: java

I come from C++ background, where the field of a class are initialized inside the constructor. But here is java I see that I can initialize then while declaring, which is different from C++.

So, I my question was which is the best/traditional practice to initialize the field members of any class. Is it...

- at the time to declaring?

  class testClass
  {
  private int x = 100;
  }
- using non-static scope?

  class testClass{
  private int x;
  {
  x = 100;
  }
  }
- or inside of a constructor?

  class testClass{
  private int x;
  testClass(){x = 100;}
  }

( Because I of my background I am a little biased towards initializing field members inside of a constructor.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a 'best practice' for initializing member variables. Obviously in Java you can initialize them in the declaration which is fine, or you can do it from the constructor. Unless you need to do something complicated (i.e. obtain a reference to a DataSource or something like that which might only be available with arguments passed in to the constructor).

In other words, there isn't a 'right way' of doing it, consistency is probably more important.

That said, bear in mind that Java will initialise uninitialised member variables for you if you don't do it. e.g. `int` variables will be set to 0, `boolean` variables will be set to false, any objects will be set to null, etc.

Comment: And because of that, you usually do not have any fields that have a choice of where to be initialized. Constants are declared as static fields; for some complex objects (for example DB connection) you always need to pass some parameters (so it can only go to constructor and nowhere else) and some primitive variables usually have a very short lifespan so they are declared in each method separately.

Comment: I think constructor way is more preferable to me. I was trying to stay away from language dependent approaches.

Comment: @iamcreasy: Well, as I already said, if your code is designed well, usually you only have fields that are initialized using some parameters - therefore it is impossible for them to be in declaration. Can you give me any real life example of field initializer that can be placed near field declaration?

Comment: Max, sometimes (for example) I need to use a Map or an ArrayList for the class, they don't need any special parameters and can be initialised at the declaration. But often, as you say, you need parameters to initialise yours variables (or even dependency injection, which would probably be the better practice).

Comment: I initilize as much as possible directly after the declaration. The reason is the fact that you usually have more than one constructor sooner or later. Also if they are not initialized (especiall stuff like `class Thing { List<Parts> parts = new ArrayList<Parts>() ... }` ) a reader might assume part could be null, while in fact it always refers to an Array which is worst case empty.

Answer (score 1):

You should write the code which appears to be the simplest and clearest.  I prefer declaring and initialising a simple value in one line and breaking up more complex lines.

You might find this notiation interesting.

```
private final List<String> words = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
```

or using double brace notation.

```
private final Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>() {{
    put("one", 1);
    put("two", 2);
    put("three", 3);
}};
```

Answer (score 1):

Though there is no 'best practice' there are some situations where certain methods work best.

For example, if you have a simple initialization value, then you can do it along with declaration.

If you have complex initialization logic (e.g array initialization), it can go inside the constructor.

Initializer blocks (non-static scope) are useful if you want to share common initialization code across constructors.

You can look at following link for more details http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I get your question right but do you want to know how to initialize variables in a class?

```
    private String s;

public EditListener(String s){
    this.s = s;
}
```

Comment: not how, but when one should do it and why one should do it then.

Comment: He wants to know if it is better to do `this.s = "abc"` or `private String s = "abc"`

Comment: Oh, I've been told to do this in the constructor. so this.s = "abc".

Comment: @Max I think you mean `private String s; public MyClass() { this.s = "abc"; } ` or `private String s = "abc";` ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Indeed I do, however my laziness exceeds my will to explain it that much thoroughly :D

Comment: @Max, My laziness makes me prefer the second option.